# Blue bar for "Google Maps is Using Your Location" missing

Tags: ios, google-maps

Typically, if Google Maps is closed while in use, there will be a blue bar indicating that Google Maps is still in use. Recently this bar has stopped appearing for me.

Why might the location bar have stopped showing up?

[image: Blue Location Usage bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### iOS 11

According to [Techcrunch](https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/26/ios-11s-blue-bar-will-shame-apps-that-overzealously-access-your-location/), iOS 11 will show the blue location bar when an app is using your location ***regardless*** of your privacy settings.

> In iOS 10, if an app was set to use location “Only While Using the App”, and you pressed the Home button, a blue bar would appear. **In iOS 11, the blue bar functionality has been expanded to those apps that are set to “Always,” too.**
>
> That means the blue status bar displays when those apps are using the continuous background location service – sort of like how the green bar shows up when a phone call is active, but you’ve exited from the Phone app to go to your home screen.

---

### iOS 10

Check **Settings → Privacy → Location Services → Google Maps** and make sure location access for Google Maps is set to "**While using the app**". The blue bar won't show up if it's set to "**Always**".

[image: location settings]